# Many to many association with structs

Tags: go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I have this data structure here :
[image]

And I am having an issue linking the many-to-many association between Historique and Medicament. (History is all the time a patient went doctor, treatment are the treatment he received, medicament the medicament prescribed)

I have this code here and I can't find a way to link them with all these foreign keys !

```golang
type Traitement struct {
    Histo_id         int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Histo_patient_id int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Histo_medecin_id int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Medicament_id    int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Debut_traitement string
    Fin_traitement   string
}
type Medicament struct {
    ID          int          `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Nom         string       `gorm:"column:medicament_nom"`
    Description string       `gorm:"column:medicament_desc"`
    Historique  []Historique `gorm:"many2many:tt_traitement"`
}
type Historique struct {
    Fk_patient_id        string `json:"-" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Date_consultation    string
    Fk_maladie_id        uint `json:"-" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Fk_compte_medecin_id uint
    Maladie              Maladie      `gorm:"ForeignKey:ID;AssociationForeignKey:Fk_maladie_id"`
    Medicament           []Medicament `gorm:"many2many:tt_traitement"`
}

func GetPatientWithDiseases(id uint) (*Patient, error) {
    patient := &Patient{}
    err := GetDB().Preload("Historique.Maladie").Preload("Historique.Traitement.Medicament").Find(&patient, id).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return patient, nil
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a lucky try, I had an error that led me to the good path.

I removed the Traitement struct, and the many_to_many and `[]Historique` in the Medicament struct. I only kept:

```golang
type Historique struct {
    ID                   int    `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Fk_patient_id        string `json:"-" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Date_consultation    string
    Fk_maladie_id        uint         `json:"-"`
    Fk_compte_medecin_id uint         `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Maladie              Maladie      `gorm:"ForeignKey:ID;AssociationForeignKey:Fk_maladie_id"`
    Medicament           []Medicament `gorm:"many2many:tt_traitement"`
}

type Medicament struct {
    ID          int    `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Nom         string `gorm:"column:medicament_nom"`
    Description string `gorm:"column:medicament_desc"`
}


func GetPatientWithDiseases(id uint) (*Patient, error) {
    patient := &Patient{}
    err := GetDB().Preload("Historique.Maladie").Preload("Historique.Medicament").Find(&patient, id).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return patient, nil
}
```

And things worked ! I just had to rename some of my columns, but as it is a dummy database, it wasn't an issue :) !

I hope this can help someone out there !